# Is $\mathbf{P_W} = \mathbf{X}(\mathbf{W}^T\mathbf{W})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T$ a projection matrix on to the column space of $\mathbf{X}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, projection-matrices

Consider $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ as the design matrix, which is full rank, and $\mathbf{W} = (\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{1}_n\mathbf{1}_n^T)\mathbf{X}$ as the centered design matrix.

I was wondering if $\mathbf{P_X} = \mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T$ is a projection matrix on the column space of $\mathbf{X}$, then would $\mathbf{P_W} = \mathbf{X}(\mathbf{W}^T\mathbf{W})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T$ be also a projection matrix on to the same column space of $\mathbf{X? }$

Comment: $P_X$ is the orthogonal projector onto $\mathrm{Im}(X).$ I am not sure what $P_W$ is. Note that $\mathrm{Im}(X)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(W)$ need not be the same space (in fact, $W \perp 1,$ whereas $X$ need not be perpendicular to $1.$